# How to correctly use subdirs with projected volumes and configMaps

Tags: docker, kubernetes, subdirectory, docker-volume

I have an nginx web server deployed with docker swarm, and I want to be able to deploy it also with kubernetes.

Right now I'm having trouble inserting the nginx configuration files into the container.

I'll first post here what I already do in docker swarm, and then what I tried in kubernetes.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM    "nginx:1.19.1-alpine"   AS nginx
[...]
RUN                                                             \
        rm -fv  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf                           && \
        ln -svT /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf                 \
                /etc/nginx/nginx.conf                           && \
        rm -frv /etc/nginx/conf.d                               && \
        ln -svT /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d                     \
                /etc/nginx/conf.d
[...]
```

Basically I set up the image so that I can place my custom nginx config files into `/usr/local/etc/` instead of `/etc/`

Docker swarm:

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```
configs:
    nginx_conf:
        file: /run/configs/www/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    nginx_conf_security-parameters:
        file: /run/configs/www/etc/nginx/conf.d/security-parameters.conf
    nginx_conf_server:
        file: /run/configs/www/etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf

networks:
    alejandro-colomar:

services:
    www:
        configs:
        -
            mode: 0440
            source: nginx_conf
            target: /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        -
            mode: 0440
            source: nginx_conf_security-parameters
            target: /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/security-parameters.conf
        -
            mode: 0440
            source: nginx_conf_server
            target: /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints:
                -   node.role == worker
            replicas: 1
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
        image: "alejandrocolomar/www:0.16-a6-kube"
        networks:
        -
            "alejandro-colomar"
        ports:
        -   "32001:8080"

version: "3.8"
```

Here I take the nginx custom config files, which I first put in `/run/configs/` with a script so that they are in ram, and introduce them in the container as configs in the right place (`/usr/local/etc/nginx/` and its subdir `conf.d/`).

I'd like to do the same in kubernetes, and I read that I should use a projected volume for that (if it's doable with normal volumes or in some other way, without having to use any dirty workarounds, I'm also open to that), so I tried the following (after seeing some examples which weren't very clear to me):

`config.sh`:

```
kubectl create configmap "nginx-conf-cm"                        \
        --from-file "/run/configs/www/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
kubectl create configmap "nginx-conf-security-parameters-cm"    \
        --from-file "/run/configs/www/etc/nginx/conf.d/security-parameters.conf"
kubectl create configmap "nginx-conf-server-cm"                 \
        --from-file "/run/configs/www/etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf"
```

`deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: www-deploy
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            service: www-svc
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                service: www-svc
        spec:
            containers:
            -
                image: "alejandrocolomar/www:0.16-a6-kube"
                name: www-container
                volumeMounts:
                -
                    mountPath: /usr/local/etc/nginx/
                    name: nginx-volume
                    readOnly: true
            volumes:
            -
                name: nginx-volume
                projected:
                    sources:
                    -
                        configMap:
                            name: nginx-conf-cm
                            path: "nginx.conf"
                    -
                        configMap:
                            name: nginx-conf-security-parameters-cm
                            path: "conf.d/security-parameters.conf"
                    -
                        configMap:
                            name: nginx-conf-server-cm
                            path: "conf.d/server.conf"
```

`service.yaml`: (This one I put it here only for completeness)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: www
spec:
    ports:
    -
        nodePort: 32001
        port: 8080
    selector:
        service: www-svc
    type: NodePort
```

The deployment failed, of course, but it wasn't very wrong I think.  When I entered in the container to debug it, the problem was that the three files were placed into `/usr/local/etc/nginx/`, and the subdir `conf.d/` was not created:

```
/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/usr/local/etc/nginx/security-parameters.conf
/usr/local/etc/nginx/server.conf
```

How should I fix that (presumably in `deployment.yaml`) so that I have the following files in the container?:

```
/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/security-parameters.conf
/usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this. One solution would be to create 3 separate volumes from these individual config maps and mount each one into its appropriate destination file/folder.

```
volumes:
        - name: nginx-cm
          configMap:
              name: nginx-conf-cm
        - name: nginx-sec
          configMap:
              name: nginx-conf-security-parameters-cm
        - name: nginx-serv
          configMap:
              name: nginx-conf-server-cm

        ...
        containers:
            -
                image: "alejandrocolomar/www:0.16-a6-kube"
                name: www-container
                volumeMounts:
                -   mountPath: /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
                    name: nginx-cm
                    subPath: nginx.conf
                    readOnly: true
                -   mountPath: /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/security-parameters.conf
                    name: nginx-sec
                    subPath: security-parameters.conf
                    readOnly: true
                -   mountPath: /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf
                    name: nginx-serv
                    subPath: server.conf
                    readOnly: true
```

using `mountPath` and `subPath` in `volumeMounts` allows you to pick specific file from a given config map (doesn't matter much since you have on file per cm) and mount it as a file (not overriding the other content in the existing folder).

To explain a bit the code above:

```
-   mountPath: /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    name: nginx-cm
    subPath: nginx.conf
```

tells kubernetes to use volume with the `name` of `nignx-cm` (defined in a volume section). Pick file `nginx.conf` (via `subpath`) that can be found in the associated config map and expose it in the container (`mountPath`) at the location `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

*I have not run the code so there might be typos*

PS: note that it might be better to create a custom configuration file inside of `../etc/nginx/conf.d/` instead of overriding `../etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. That way you wouldn't need to worry about destroying the original files `../etc/nginx/` and you could mount the whole volume instead of using `subpath` (to avoid issues with config updates)

Comment: Oh, that's really nice!!  I didn't know that one could use volumes without overriding the content of the existing folder.  That's why I tried with projected volumes.  So I don't need projected volumes anymore (yet)! :)

Comment: Sadly, I do need to write my custom `nginx.conf`. The reason is that there's a line in it (`keepalive_timeout  65;`) which I want to replace by `keepalive_timeout 10s 10s;`.  And I didn't find a solution that doesn't involve replacing the file.

Comment: However, the only files there will be the ones I place with `deployment.yaml`.  The original nginx configuration files will be in `/etc/nginx/`, and mine will be in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/`.  Initially I thought that I couldn't mount two volumes one being a subdir of the other, but now I'm having doubts.  Maybe I don't need `subPath` in this case either if the directory structure can be maintained anyhow.

Comment: No you don't need subpaths if you are not worried about overriding existing files. Yes, you can mount one volume as a subdirectory of another mounted volume. There is a lot of different solutions to this problem.

Comment: Another thing about subpaths is that your configmaps may contain a lot of different configurations for different containers and you might not want to mount all the files from one config map into all those mount points. Subpaths allow you to cherrypick which exact files from configmap will be copied to which location.

Comment: Btw, I do believe that you can override that default `keep_alive` in the `server` and `location` context as well.

Comment: I'll investigate that.  I tried a long time ago without success, but maybe I should try again :)